# Другая, правящая(,) партия выглядела совершенно сбитой с толку происходящим

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли здесь ставить вторую запятую, после *правящая*? В контексте речь сначала идёт об одной из двух рассматриваемых партий, а потом - в данном предложении - о другой (то есть о второй из этих двух) партии, которая являлась правящей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Другая, правящая(,) партия выглядела совершенно сбитой с толку происходящим.*

.

Правильно с одной запятой:

***Другая, правящая** партия выглядела совершенно сбитой с толку происходящим.*

См. [**ПАС:**](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/#id-6%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%C2%A783)

> **§83**
>
> Пояснительные согласованные определения не выделяются, а
> лишь **отделяются** от поясняемого определения **запятой**. Пояснение
> возникает при особых по значению определениях – они имеют общий
> неконкретизированный, неопределенный смысл. Второе, поясняющее
> определение снимает неопределенность:
>
> <…>
>
> *Совсем **другие, городские** звуки слышались снаружи и внутри квартала.*